# How change the height of kendodatepicker dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project I used **kendoDatePicker** as below:

```
 <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Content/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BirthDate").kendoDatePicker()
    });
</script>
```

and a part of my view is as below that will be shown with kendodatepicket:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" align="right" style="margin-top: 45px">
     <input type="text" id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" required class="form-control" placeholder="تاریخ تولد">
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

as you see the below picture is the dropdown of datepicker and the height of this too much:
[image]

How can shorten the height of this with CSS?
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: What kind of font / language is that? Have you verified this issue also presents when just English characters are used?

Comment: This is Persian font. It was good before but I do not know for what it gets like this. What is exactly the CSS class for this dropdown to make this dropdown height smaller or is there any jquery function to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have understood what my problem was!
I had written a style like below in the view and this style had Caused disturbance in this datepicker:

```
<style>
      a {
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px
    }
</style>
```